# MySQL & Regex: match the whole word only or skip URLs?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I use the query below for searching,

```
SELECT
pg_id AS ID, 
pg_url AS URL,
pg_title AS Title,
pg_content_1 AS Content_1,
pg_content_2 AS Content_2,
parent_id AS Parent_id,

EXTRACT(DAY FROM pg_created) AS Date,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pg_created) AS Month,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pg_created) AS Year

FROM root_pages

WHERE root_pages.pg_cat_id = '2'
AND root_pages.parent_id != root_pages.pg_id
AND root_pages.pg_hide != '1'
AND root_pages.pg_url != 'cms'
AND root_pages.pg_content_1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search."[[:>:]]'
OR root_pages.pg_content_2 REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search."[[:>:]]'

ORDER BY root_pages.pg_created DESC
```

I works fine but I don't want it to search the keyword in the URL address such as,

If I search for the keyword of **home**, the query will search any matches of 'home' in the URLs below and return them as the result too:

http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/xx/eurostat/**home**/

http://ec.europa.eu/**home**-affairs/doc_centre/xx.pdf

How can I fix the query so that it won't match the keyword in an URL or it should match the whole word only?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on how your application works, it might make more sense to strip the URLs out first. Running any regex on multiple rows will slow down drastically as your data grows larger. So instead of doing a regex for every single search, do a regex once before inserting the data.

Comment: @colin: thanks for the tips. I don't think strip_tag will work though as if I strip this url - <a href="http://xx/eurostat/home/">http://xx/eurostat/home/</a> - will get http://xx/eurostat/home/ as the remaining string and the query is still searching the keyword in this string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Found my own solution and it seems to work fine as it skips searching the text in the column with **http://**

```
SELECT
pg_id AS ID, 
pg_url AS URL,
pg_title AS Title,
pg_content_1 AS Content_1,
pg_content_2 AS Content_2,
parent_id AS Parent_id,

EXTRACT(DAY FROM pg_created) AS Date,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pg_created) AS Month,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pg_created) AS Year

FROM root_pages

WHERE root_pages.pg_cat_id = '2'
AND root_pages.parent_id != root_pages.pg_id
AND root_pages.pg_hide != '1'
AND root_pages.pg_url != 'cms'
AND root_pages.pg_content_1 LIKE '%".$search."%'
OR root_pages.pg_content_2 LIKE '%".$search."%'

AND root_pages.pg_content_1 NOT LIKE '%http://%'
AND root_pages.pg_content_2 NOT LIKE '%http://%'

ORDER BY root_pages.pg_created DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) implementation for MySQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION strip_tags( x longtext) RETURNS longtext
LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE sstart INT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE ends INT UNSIGNED;
    SET sstart = LOCATE('<', x, 1);
    REPEAT
        SET ends = LOCATE('>', x, sstart);
        SET x = CONCAT(SUBSTRING( x, 1 ,sstart -1) ,SUBSTRING(x, ends +1 )) ;
        SET sstart = LOCATE('<', x, 1);
    UNTIL sstart < 1 END REPEAT;
return x;
END;
```

(found [here](http://youropensource.com/projects/626-strip_tags-in-mysql))

And then your query would look like this:

```
AND STRIP_TAGS(root_pages.pg_content_1) REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search."[[:>:]]'
OR STRIP_TAGS(root_pages.pg_content_2) REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search."[[:>:]]'
```

However, this implementation may be slow and unreliable, so I'd suggest a different approach:

1. create a new column, for example `search`
2. insert there raw (=php strip_tagged) search data for each row in your table (may even be a combination of the two columns you use for searching)
3. Then you can use query like this one - `SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE search LIKE '%your_search_expression%'` or even [fulltext keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) if you want. (use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) instead of REGEXP as it is [faster](http://thingsilearn.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/mysql-query-speed-regexp-vs-like/)).

Comment: thanks for the tips. I don't think strip_tag will work though as if I strip this url - <a href="http://xx/eurostat/home/">http://xx/eurostat/home/</a> - will get http://xx/eurostat/home/ as the remaining string and the query is still searching the keyword in this string.

Comment: Yes, as I said, this is not quite reliable. However, you can modify the function to remove url patterns from the text as well.

Comment: thanks again. where should I keep that mysql function and evoke it? Do I have to do something like $sql ="CREATE FUNCTION strip_tags..."; then evoke it by $result = $connection->query($sql);??

Comment: Well first you need to store the function in your database. This is done by executing the CREATE FUNCTION query on the server (either in some client like MySQL workbench or PHPMyAdmin). When it's stored, you just use the function in queries as I do in my example. (the function remains stored in the database until you decide to delete it).